# FindOne with MongooseJS and then storing the result in advance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry if this sounds silly, I am still learning server-side Javascript. I have this code in my app.js file.

```
var test;

UserModel.findOne({name: 'guest'}, function(err, user) {
    test = user.name;
});

console.log(test);
```

I understand that this doesn't work because `UserModel.findOne` is async and so everything has to happen within the callback. E.g. `console.log(test)` could execute before the `UserModel.findOne` finishes.

**Question**

If I declare `var test` in my app.js file, is there a way of getting the value of `user.name` (via `UserModel.findOne`) into it?

The reason why I am doing this is because I am hoping to retrieve all these information from the database in advance. So that I don't have to make a database query every time need a user's name.

If this idea is unsound, are there similar alternatives?

**Edit/Update**

This isn't used for authentication/log-in. I intend for all users to have access to the variable `test` and its content.

Essentially, I am asking why doesn't the variable `test` set permanently to `user.name` but instead only got step within the scope of the callback. And, is it possible to set the variable permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that all users of your app would share that `test` variable, this seems like a bad idea.  This is the sort of data you would store in the user's session if you don't want to look it up as needed.

**EDIT**

As long as you're declaring `test` at either global or module scope, it is set permanently in the `findOne` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it is intended for all users to share that test variable. It is not used for log-in/authentication purposes. Perhaps I should edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I am such an idiot! It IS set permanently in the callback. The problem was calling console.log(test) immediately after findOne, forgetting that it is aysnc. I used setInterval to run console.log(test) a few seconds later and the correct result showed. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

The example:

```
var users = {};
function getUser(username, callback) {
    if (typeof users[username] !== 'undefined') {
        callback(users[username]);
    } else {
        Users.findOne({"name":username}, function(err, user) {
            users[username] = user;
            callback(user);
        });
    };
};
```

This will always return the named user either from the cache or from mongodb. It is called the same way as the findOne:

getUser('guest', function(user) {
       console.log(user);
   });

After that you could access a user from the cache directly or assign it to a variable. But you must ensure that getUser has succeeded first.

One of the hardest things about Node.js is to understand that code is called outside of the normal flow of the written source. It is not enough for the code to follow the call to a function with a callback.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It has been resolved. I took a break from node to do some C + Python and forgot how the async work. :p But thanks for the advice and great code. I'll be using it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can apply the result to a variable in a higher scope for example this should work;

```
var test;

function getTest() {
   console.log(test);
}

UserModel.findOne({name: 'guest'}, function(err, user) {
   test = user.name;

   getTest();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It would also work if I move "console.log(test);" inside the findOne callback. I was actually hoping to: 1. make a database query, 2. store the result in test, 3. allow all users and future javascript to access the information in test. However, "test = user.name" in the callback doesn't seem to set the variable permanently, only within the scope of the callback.

Comment: Are you declaring test outside the callback? If so it would be available outside the callback, but only after the callback has executed. If you are using it as a cache you should be able to check whether the variable was already defined and not make the request again. I'll post an example as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer by hexacyanide below. Using a callback in the async callback saved me for my project with this same problem.

[Set Variable to result of Mongoose Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938469/set-variable-to-result-of-mongoose-find)