# How to return query results to a variable using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am still in learning stage of Node.js and Moongoose and i have a scenario where in

- I am taking value(ABC) from form submit.It is a user's Name
- Then i am searching for that name in users collection(User)
- Fetch that user and write its ObjectID in another schema(article) using ref.

**My logic:**

```
article.owner = User.findOne({ 'name' : 'ABC' })
    .exec(function (err, user){
         return user
    })
```

But it is not returning results. I referred some other answers and tried `async.parallel` but still i am not able to save ABC user's objectID in article schema at `article.owner` i am always getting null.

Please suggest me any other better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Node has to do any I/O, like reading from a database, it will be done asynchronously. Methods like `User.findOne` and `Query#exec` will never return a result upfront so `article.owner` will not be properly undefined in your example.

The result of an asynchronous query will only be available inside of your callback, which is only invoked when your I/O has finished

```
article.owner = User.findOne({ name : 'ABC' }) .exec(function (err, user){    
    // User result only available inside of this function!
    console.log(user) // => yields your user results
})

// User result not available out here!
console.log(article.owner) // => actually set to return of .exec (undefined)
```

What asynchronous code execution means in the above example: When Node.js hits `article.owner = User.findOne...` it will execute `User.findOne().exec()` and then move straight onto `console.log(article.owner)` before `.exec` has even finished.

Hope that helps clarify. It takes a while to get used to async programming it but it will make sense with more practice

**Update** To answer your specific problem, one possible solution would be:

```
User.findOne({name: 'ABC'}).exec(function (error, user){
    article.owner = user._id; // Sets article.owner to user's _id
    article.save()            // Persists _id to DB, pass in another callback if necessary
});
```

Remember to use [Query#populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) if you want to load your user with the article like so:

```
Article.findOne({_id: <some_id>}).populate("owner").exec(function(error, article) {
    console.log(article.owner); // Shows the user result
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer C Blanchard :-) But this answer did not solve my basic question of how to get Username into my other collection(article) where i need to assign this user's objectID at article.owner using ref. Kindly let me know if you need still more details

Comment: damphat's earlier response was the answer to your solution, I just wanted to help you understand his answer. I'll update my answer in any case since there's more information about the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
User.findOne({ 'name' : 'ABC' }) .exec(function (err, user){
    article.owner = user.fieldName;
})
```

Comment: So if you added "console.log(article.owner);" outside of that function, it would print user.fieldName?

Comment: no michaelAdam, console.log must be inside, or you can use npm 'async' to wait for a callback

Answer (score 1):

The answer by hexacyanide shows how to carry data from the async db find callback via another callback. Saved me for my project!

[Set Variable to result of Mongoose Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938469/set-variable-to-result-of-mongoose-find)